# How to return an array of numbers that represent lengths of elements string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, oop

If an array was: ['hey', 'you', 'muddy']
The expected output should be: [3, 3, 5]

This is what I have so far:

```
function lengths(arr) {
  numbersArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    numbersArray = arr[i].length;
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `numbersArray .push(arr[i].length)` or even simpler, replace the whole function body with  `numbersArray = arr.map(i => i.length)`

Comment: also can use map with return string.length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to push the `length` of every item (using [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)) and return the array in the end:

```js
function lengths(arr) {
  const numbersArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    numbersArray.push(arr[i].length);
  }
  return numbersArray;
}

console.log( lengths(['hey', 'you', 'muddy']) );
```

Another solution using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
function lengths(arr) {
 return arr.map(str => str.length);
}

console.log( lengths(['hey', 'you', 'muddy']) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const getStringLength = (arr) => {
  return arr.map((item) => item.length);
}
console.log(getStringLength(['hello', 'world']));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function lengths(arr) {
  return arr.map(el => el.length)
}
```

Array.map is commonly used in such things. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
const arrStrLen =(a)=>a.map((i)=>i.length);

console.log(arrStrLen(['hey', 'you', 'muddy']));

console.log(arrStrLen(['How','to','return']));
```